# I want an arbitrarily-large buffer in Linux/C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, virtual-memory

Basically I want an arbitrarily large stack. I know that's not possible, but could I set aside a few terabytes of my virtual address space for it? I'd like to be able to start at the beginning and walk up the buffer as far as I need, and Linux can bring in pages from physical memory on an as-needed basis. Is something like that possible? Would it have the same performance as just malloc-ing a buffer? Would there be a way to signal to Linux that you're done with the memory once you pop the stack?

EDIT: I'm wanting this because I want to optimize a recursive/parallel algorithm that allocates lots of memory on each call. Malloc is too slow for me and I don't want all the threads to trip on each other inside of malloc's locks. So basically it would be my own run-time stack alongside the real one (one for each thread).

Actually, as long as the run-time stack is big enough that should be good enough. Is there a way to know/ensure the size of the stack? In a 64-bit address space there's enough room for several threads to be stack-allocating gigabytes of data. Is that doable?

It looks like pthread_attr_setstacksize could work for new threads, but that doesn't help much if you can be called from any thread ...

Comment: What's wrong with `std::stack`?

Comment: I would suggest that if you want an arbitrarily large stack you ask for *that*, instead of asking for the way you think you want to proceed. Or is there some other constraint here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create such an allocation using `mmap()` with the `MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_NORESERVE | MAP_PRIVATE` flags.  When you want to free it back to the system, use `munmap()`.

Note that the only way you will find out if insufficient memory is available to satisfy your actual use is by your process receiving a `SIGSEGV` - but this is comes with the territory of asking for a giant mapping much larger than available memory.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want a large stack, you could always change `ulimit -s`. It can be very large, at least on 64-bit platforms.

If you `mmap` anonymous space, it won't actually be allocated physical pages until you touch it. You'll need to either set vm_overcommit or have enough swap (unless you have that much physical RAM). Of course, `mmap`'ing anonymous space is exactly what `malloc` does when you ask for a lot of memory.

You can tell Linux you're done with the pages using `madvise`. If you call `MADV_DONTNEED`, then Linux will [discard the pages](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=mm/madvise.c;h=74bf193eff04fdeea6c433675a3705adbeb3c0f1;hb=1ea6b8f48918282bdca0b32a34095504ee65bab5#l148) and they should be zero-filled next time you try to access them.

Comment: So if I set vm_overcommit and then mmap() a terabyte of anonymous space, I'm good to start using it?

Is there a lot of overhead in madvise (since it zero-fills the pages)?

Comment: @Chris: Zero-fill is actually done when you first access the page. It *can* be turned off, but its normally done for security reasons—to make sure that memory freed by one process (or the kernel) can't be read by another. Keep in mind also that vm_overcommit can't keep you from actually running out of memory (if you don't have 1TB of RAM/swap), and you try to access all that, the likely result is SIGKILL.

Comment: Awesome thanks! So I looked at madvise() and didn't see a way to say "I'm done with these pages so evict them next if you ever need room, don't bother copying them to swap space either." Looks like that's probably not supported ...

Comment: @Chris: That's what `MADV_DONTNEED` does. Assuming the kernel reclaims the pages (which it will if there is any memory pressure, or maybe even if not): If you mapped an actual file, the next time you use the pages, the file will be re-read; if you've mapped anonymous space (with MAP_ANONYMOUS), then next time you read the pages, they will be zero-filled (to avoid exposing the previous contents that physical RAM, which may have last been last used by a different app)

Comment: Note that you can use the `MAP_NORESERVE` flag to `mmap()` to request the overcommit-style behaviour on a particular mapping, even if overcommit is off.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `malloc`ing memory that size (or `new`ing it, or creating it on the stack) will almost definitely result in a `std::bad_alloc` error because you're trying to create it all in contiguous memory - and you most definitely don't have that much uninterrupted, contiguous memory due to fragmentation.

If you use a `std::` container like a `deque` or a container adapter like a `stack` (anything without contiguous memory - i.e. not a vector) then it will use heap memory in pieces which are expandable.  This will get you around that `bad_alloc` error.

So, its possible, but don't try and make the memory contiguous - and if you're allowed use a `std::`container/adapter.

PS: if you need large memory spaces, you could consider a using a list of dynamically allocated buffers (`malloc`ed pointers) that are of a size large enough to be usable but small enough to be likely not to trigger a `bad_alloc` exception).

Comment: This isn't true on 64-bit Linux. Assuming you have the swap (or physical memory) to back it, several TB of contiguous address space is no problem.

Comment: I believed the same of Windows, though I don't have anything to back it up.  Isn't that one of the big reasons we have virtual memory?  I know I've allocated 2GB vectors on my 32bit windows machine before

Comment: Maybe, I've run into bad_alloc a few times when allocating spaces much smaller than that on the linux(like) installation we use at work though.  I guess it's more platform specific than I'd realized.

Comment: You may have some resource limits set up, or maybe you have vm_overcommit turned off and don't have enough swap to enable it. But finding several TiB in the 256TiB virtual address space current 64-bit processors have shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that resources are always limited by physical constraints: the number of atoms in the universe is probably finite... So arbitrarily large buffers cannot stricto sensu exist...

However, you could use Linux [mmap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) system call to view a portion of file as a virtual memory segment. If it is very big (bigger than RAM), you'll have performance issues. Consider tuning it with [madvise](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/madvise.2.html) (& perhaps `readahead`) system calls.

Maybe even using GCC [__bultin_prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) function could be useful (but I'm sure that `madvise` is more relevant).

If you really have a terabyte sized stack, tuning your application will be very important. Learn to use [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/). I hope you have a powerful machine!

<strike>And this is not really enough for the call stack (it probably is limited, e.g. thru [setrlimit](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) ...) See also [sigaltstack](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaltstack) (for the stack used for signal delivery).</strike>

But what do you really want to achieve? Very big call stacks seem suspicious to me... Or is your stack not the call stack??

Comment: He doesn't say "call stack" anywhere.  Just a stack

Answer (score -1):

```
Create stack using two queues in that way you can have variable length of stack, which will increase as you require.

implementing stack using two queues

initially q1 is full and q2 empty
1] tranfer elements from q1 to q2 till last element left in q1
2] loop till q2 is not empty
deque element from q2 and again push in q2 till last element is left in q2
transfer this last element in q1
reduce size of q2 by 1
3]finally q1 contains all elements in reverse order as in stack
eg

1]
q1 = 1 2 3 4
q2 =
2]
3 deques till last element left in q1
q1 = 4
q2 = 1 2 3
3]
deque and again queue q2 till last element left
q1 = 4
q2 = 3 1 2
4] deque q2 and queue q1
q1 = 4 3
q2 = 1 2
5] again
deque and queue q2 till last element left
q1= 4 3
q2= 2 1
6] queue q1
q1= 4 3 2
7] queue last element of q2 to q1
q1= 4 3 2 1
```