# How to Change the Maximum Size of a malloc() Allocation in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc

As far as I can tell, calling `malloc()` basically means the program is asking the OS for a hunk of memory. I'm writing a program to interface with a camera, in which I need to allocate chucks of memory large enough to store hundreds of images at a time (its a fast camera).

When I allocate space for about 1.9 Gb worth of images, everything works just fine. The allocation calculation is pretty simple:

```
int   allocateBurst( int numImages ) 
{
    int streamSize = ZIMAGESIZE * numImages; 
    data.images = new unsigned short [streamSize];
    return 0; 
}
```

But as soon as I go over the 2 Gb limit, I get runtime errors like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
    what():  std::bad_alloc
```

It seems like 2 Gigs might be the maximum size that I can allocate at once. I have 32 Gigs of ram, and would like to simply be able to allocate larger pieces of memory in one allocation. Is this possible?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want an arbitrarily-large buffer in Linux/C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317011/i-want-an-arbitrarily-large-buffer-in-linux-c-c)

Comment: Is the binary compiled as 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, its compiled as 64-Bit

Comment: To avoid "sign bit" issues with the data, I recommend using `unsigned` integers.  I have not come across negative pixel values, negative picture dimensions or negative bits per pixel.  And besides, `unsigned` gives you an extra bit to play with.

Comment: "in one allocation"... do you really need >2 GB of contiguous memory?

Comment: Actually yes. Its a camera that takes 11Mb images at 100FPS, data stacks up pretty quick

Comment: That doesn't justify requiring 2 GB of *contiguous* memory.  You could, for example, pre-allocate many 11 MB chunks and rotate among them.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Yes, I could do that, and that is my backup plan. I would like to find a nice way of increasing the allocation size since I have plenty of memory. Its just preferable to making the program logic more convoluted.

Comment: Are you saying that "streamSize" is 2^31 or that `streamSize * sizeof(unsigned short)` is >= 2^31?

Comment: `streamSize` would be 2^31 in the max case I guess. Its possible the size I'm trying to store with it would be too big

Answer (score 1):

There may be an underlying issue that the OS can't grant your large memory allocation because it is using memory for other applications.  Check with your OS to see what the limits are.

Also know that some OS's will "page" memory to the hard disk.  When your program asks for memory outside the page, the OS will swap pages with the hard disk.  Knowing this, I recommend a classic technique of "Double Buffering" or "Multiple Buffering".

You will need at least two threads:  reading and writing.  One thread is responsible for reading data from the camera and placing into a buffer.  When it fills up a buffer, it starts on another buffer.  Meanwhile the writing thread is starting at the buffer and writing it to disk (block file writes).  When the writing thread finishes a buffer, it starts on the next one.  The buffers should be in a circular sequence to reuse them.

The magic is to have enough buffers so that the reader never catches up to the writer.

Since you are using a couple of small buffers, you should not get any errors from the OS.

The are methods to optimize this, such as obtaining static buffers from the OS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using a signed 32-bit variable to describe an unsigned 64-bit number.

Use "size_t" instead of "int" for holding the storage count. This has nothing to do with what you intend to store, just how large a count of them you need.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int /*argc*/, const char** /*argv*/)
{
  int units = 2;

  // 32-bit signed, i.e. 31-bit numbers.
  int intSize = units * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

  // 64-bit values (ULL suffix)
  size_t sizetSize = units * 1024ULL * 1024ULL * 1024ULL;

  std::cout << "intSize = " << intSize << ", sizetSize = " << sizetSize << std::endl;

  try {
    unsigned short* intAlloc = new unsigned short[intSize];
    std::cout << "intAlloc = " << intAlloc << std::endl;
    delete [] intAlloc;
  } catch (std::bad_alloc) {
    std::cout << "intAlloc failed (std::bad_alloc)" << std::endl;
  }

  try {
    unsigned short* sizetAlloc = new unsigned short[sizetSize];
    std::cout << "sizetAlloc = " << sizetAlloc << std::endl;
    delete [] sizetAlloc;
  } catch (std::bad_alloc) {
    std::cout << "sizetAlloc failed (std::bad_alloc)" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output (g++ -m64 -o test test.cpp under Mint 15 64 bit with g++ 4.7.3 on a virtual machine with 4Gb of memory)

```
intSize = -2147483648, sizetSize = 2147483648
intAlloc failed
sizetAlloc = 0x7f55affff010
```

Answer (score -2):

```
int   allocateBurst( int numImages ) 
{
    // change that from int to long
    long streamSize = ZIMAGESIZE * numImages; 
    data.images = new unsigned short [streamSize];
    return 0; 
}
```

Try using

```
long
```

OR

cast the result of the allocateBurst function to "uint_64" and the return type of the function to uint_64

Because int you allocate 32 bit allocation while long or uint_64 allocates 64 bit allocation which could possibly allocate more memory space for you.

Hope that helps

Comment: The OS doesn't care what you're planning to use the memory you allocated for.

Comment: I disagree with you as when some applications requires a large chunk of memory that could occupy that space for a longer time and makes other processes waiting for the CPU who are suspended or blocked forever ... then in that case the OS Memory management system must care about what the memory is allocated for